# Can some help me with the Addition of HTML elements within the Shapes using Syncfusion ej-angular using the Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, syncfusion

I am trying to follow the official documentation of `Syncfusion AngularJs` and trying to create the `Nodes` which will have `HTML Elements` such as Button, Textbox, etc embedded within them but for some reason, I am unable to get the output as they have mentioned in the documentation. I tried to search a lot but there are no relevant post hence asking the same.

Official Documentation Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/angularjs/diagram/shapes#html

One thing that is bugging me is this line. I am not sure why they have this in HTML and after that they are creating the `DIV`: `<script id="htmlTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender"></script>`

I would really appreciate if someone can help me how can I create the nodes within that I can add HTML elements of my choice.

Code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="defaultApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg">
        <title>Draw Shapes with HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/14.3.0.49/js/web/bootstrap-theme/ej.web.all.min.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/js/assets/external/jsrender.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/14.3.0.49/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/scripts/xljsondata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/14.3.0.49/js/common/ej.widget.angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/jsrender.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="./js/draw.js"></script>
            
    </head>
    
    <body ng-controller="diagramCtrl">
        <ej-diagram id="diagram" e-height="500px" e-width="700px" e-nodes="nodes"></ej-diagram>
        <button class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
    </body>     
</html>
```

My `AngularJS` code in `draw.js` file is something like this:

```
var syncApp = angular.module("defaultApp", ["ngRoute", "ejangular"]);

var diagram = ej.datavisualization.Diagram;

//Creates a html node
var nodes = [{
    name: "htmlNode",
    offsetX: 100,
    offsetY: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    type: ej.datavisualization.Diagram.Shapes.Html,
    templateId: "htmlTemplate",
    value: "Button"
}];

syncApp.controller('diagramCtrl', function($scope) {
    //Sets nodes collection to Diagram model.
    $scope.nodes = nodes;
});
```

As of now my HTML looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you try the below link?
http://ngjq.syncfusion.com/#/diagram/drawingtools

Comment: @Karthick Thanks a lot for the link. I am going through it and seems to be very useful for me. I was searching for something like this from last few hours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

On analyzing the provided code snippet you have set the htmlTemplate as a div element. If we set other than script element means htmlTemplate for the node do not gets visible. If you want to set htmlTemplate for node means then set inside script element. So that only htmlTemplate for node gets visible. We have used your HTML content inside script to show htmlTemplate for node.

```
<script id="htmlTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">                        
//Html Template                            
</script>
```

Sample: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/5z2stf0b